# SystemVerilog convert series of tasks into separate files without losing readability

Tags: verilog, system-verilog

I created a testbench for some of my code and slowly added to it over time.
It's really too big for one file, so I'd like to move the tasks to separate files.

How do I change this:

tb.v

```c
module tb
  int data;

  initial begin
    do_this;
    #10;
    do_that;
    #10;
    do_this;
    #10;    
  end

  task do_this ();
    begin
      data = 10;
    end
  endtask

  task do_that ();
    begin
      if (data==10) begin
         data = 20;
      end
      else begin
         data = 0;
      end
    end
  endtask

endmodule
```

Into something like this:

tb.v

```
module tb
  int data;

  initial begin
    do_this(data);
    #10;    data = 30; //<-- data is driven by the initial statement     and the modules
    #10;    do_that(data); //<-- data is both an input and an output
    #10;    
  end
endmodule
```

do_this.v

```
  module do_this (inout reg data); //<-- this is clearly wrong, but     gets the point across
    begin
         #5; //<-- can't use delay statement in a module like this.
         data = 10;
    end
  endmodule
```

do_that.v

```
  module do_that (inout reg data); //<-- this is clearly wrong, but     gets the point across
    begin
      if (data==10) begin
         data = 20;
      end
      else begin
         data = 0;
      end
    end
  endmodule
```

I've tried using tasks with `include, but it's too easy to lose track of how and where 'data' is modified.
I'm currently trying to use tasks with inputs and outputs, but it seems very wrong to do something like this:
`do_that(.data_in(data), .data_out(data));`

Is there a better/correct way to do something like this? (classes/packages/global variables?)

Comment: Using `include` is certainly an easy way to achieve what you want. Why do you think `do_that(.data_in(data), .data_out(data));` seems so wrong? This type of function/task calls are often encouraged because of readability.

Comment: Another way to do this is using SystemVerilog packages.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this either by using `include or using systemVerilog's packages. You can define tasks or functions inside a package and share them among multiple modules. Below is an example with packages:

```c
package p;
    function int do_this();
      return 10; 
    endfunction

    function int do_that(input int in);
      if (in==10) return 20;
      else return 0;
    endfunction
endpackage

module top;
    import p::*;
    int data;
      initial begin
        data = do_this(); 
        #10;
        data = do_that(.in(data));
        #10;
        data = do_this(); 
        #10;
      end
endmodule
```

You can define multiple packages and put each package definition in a separate file.

It is actually considered a good coding practice to use parameter names in function calls.

Also, using global variables in tasks/functions is generally not a good idea and prevents data encapsulation. It's best to pass everything to the function through local parameters to ensure there will be no unintentional changes.